# Installing Cloudify From PyPI - ERROR

Tags: cloudify

I am following the link http://getcloudify.org/guide/3.2/installation.html#installing-from-pypi, but when running the command "sudo pip install cloudify==3.2", the error occurs below:

```
...
    checking for uint8_t... yes
    checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
    checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
    checking for memmove... yes
    checking for memset... yes
    configure: creating ./config.status
    config.status: creating src/config.h
    warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Hash._MD2' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/MD2.o
    src/MD2.c:31:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-8ZRUY3/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-JeNRYe-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-8ZRUY3/pycrypto
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

Below list versions:

```
(cloudify)ubuntu@ip-172-30-2-253:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.6

(cloudify)ubuntu@ip-172-30-2-253:~$ pip --version
pip 1.5.4 from /home/ubuntu/cloudify/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

(cloudify)ubuntu@ip-172-30-2-253:~$ virtualenv --version
1.11.4
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you lack some prerequisites.

I suggest that you check all of the followings:

1. Update your system

   ```
   $sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Install needed libraries

   ```
   $sudo apt-get install python-dev gcc
   ```
3. Update pip version

   ```
   $sudo apt-get install pip
   ```
4. Update virtualenv version

   ```
   $ sudo pip install virtualenv
   ```

After those are checked you should try to install Cloudify:

```
    $pip install cloudify==3.2.1
```